# Reading the content of files uploaded on firebase cloud storage

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

The program is supposed to read the VCF files containing the genetic information of the patients, pass the data through an AI-based recommender, and then save some values from those files to the database, to print them on the screen later. I am using the Python library Scikit-allel for extracting the information of the VCF files. the problem is that I can't use the URL of the storage to get the files to be used by the library as shown in the following code:

```
storage=firebase.storage()
file=storage.child("1.vcf").get_url(None)
print(file)

callset = allel.read_vcf(file, fields=
['variants/CHROM',
 'variants/CLNDISDB',
 'variants/CLNVC',
'variants/GENEINFO',
 'variants/AF_EXAC',
'variants/CLNDN',
 'variants/ID',
 'variants/MC',
 'variants/ORIGIN',
 'variants/POS',
 'variants/SIFT_score',
 'variants/RS',
 'variants/is_snp',
 'variants/CLNSIG',
 'variants/numalt'], numbers={'ALT': 1})
sorted(callset.keys())
```

this code can work if the file is locally downloaded on the same file as the project, but when the file variable equals the URL leading to the cloud storage it says: file is not fined.